# Android Development - Sprite doesn't repaint when moving, clones itself to next position - leaving trace behind

Tags: android, image, clone, sprite, paint

I am having some issues in learning Android Programming. I got following things: A RelativeLayout to which I added a new class called "GameView" extending a SurfaceView. This "GameView" class contains an object of the "GameThread" class, a Thread-class I created.
So now my problem is, this Thread class keeps calling the onDraw() method of my SurfaceView.
Now I let the SurfaceView paint a Bitmap onto the screen and on every onDraw() call it should move 10 pixels to the right. But now my problem is, that the first image remains at its position and there appears another image 10 pixels to the right. It looks like that:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7rVL5jhBMejN2VwTWlmaG1XemM/edit?usp=sharing

Now how am I able to create a smooth moving Sprite without such a trace of cloned images?

My code:
The Main class:

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {    

  RelativeLayout rLayout;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.all);
    rLayout.addView(new GameView(this));

  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

    }
```

And the GameView class

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;

    public class GameView extends SurfaceView {

    private Bitmap bmp;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private GameThread gameThread;
    private int x = 11;

    public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    gameThread = new GameThread(this);
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            gameThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }
    });
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, 10, null);
    x += 1;
    }



    }
```

And the Game Loop class:

```
    import android.graphics.Canvas;

    public class GameThread implements Runnable{
    private GameView gameView;
    private boolean isRunning = false;

    public GameThread(GameView gameView) {
    this.gameView = gameView;
    }

    public void start() {
    isRunning = true;
    new Thread(this, "Game Thread").start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    while(isRunning) {
        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = gameView.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (gameView.getHolder()) {
                gameView.onDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if(c != null) {
                gameView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
    }   
    }
```

I hope somebody can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following before you draw the sprite:

```
canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0)
```

You need to reset the background of the canvas before you draw the next frame.

You can also try `canvas.drawARGB(100, 0, 0, 0)`. This will draw a translucent background which will allow some of the previously draw bitmaps to show through. It looks like the sprite is leaving a faint trail behind it.

Comment: I will have a look but thanks for the almost instant answer! :)

Comment: @MarcelOchs Mark this as answer by checking the right mark beside the answer if it helps you